# Include long url in sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx

I am very new in Sphinx. So sorry if it is very basic question.

I have a very long url I would like to include in my documentation. 
If I just include the link in my doc, it looks ugly because it is too long

I tried, to include it in a box doing

> Click on the following link ::
>
> ```
>    http://my_very_looooooooooooooooooooooog_url
> ```

Then, it looks much better since it is on one line only but it is not clickable anymore.

What can I do to have it clickable and on one single line ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 14):

You can use an any one of the hyperlink constructs available in reStructuredText. One example is to use an *embedded URI*, as defined in the reStructuredText specification (see, for example, the [quick reference](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#external-hyperlink-targets)), writing:

```
External hyperlinks, like `Python <http://www.python.org/>`_.
```

renders like the following:

> External hyperlinks, like [Python](http://www.python.org/).

Comment: Thank you. But I wish I can still see the url, I do not want to replace it with a link like Python in the example above.

Comment: Is this normal, the hyperlink method does not work when it is inside a block? 
If I do :      
External hyperlinks, like `Python <http://www.python.org/>`_.
this is ok (I get a clickable Python) but if I do: 

see the link below::

        External hyperlinks, like `Python <http://www.python.org/>`_.

Then I have the full line printed

Comment: The `::` starts a literal block, which is, by default, simply some text typeset in a monospace font. No other processing of the text is done (AFAIK). So yes, this is normal.

Comment: In response to your first comment, you say in the question "If I just include the link in my doc, it looks ugly because it is too long", so which do you want: to see the link or to have it shortened?

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear. What I want is ti have it on one single line, in a box you can scroll to see the full line

Comment: How about placing your link in a blockquote (which is just an indented paragraph), rather than a literal block? Replace the double colon with a single colon.

Comment: then it prints the full url (which is however clickable)

Comment: This is worthless. The objective is to embed these links in the docstrings in the code, but then the linter will fail such code.

Comment: @wvxvw - a linter was not mentioned in the question. If you've got a different question or problem, please post that as a new question. My answer wasn't trying to solve whatever problem you're facing.